# CsvHelper : Adding Headers using ClassMap throws Stackoverflow exception

Tags: csvhelper

I have a use case in which I need to write 2 lines of headers before writing actual data.

e.g

Header, Header

Name,Age as of now

Ninja, 28

I thought this can be achived using ClassMap implementation.
But when it throws me an stackoverflow exception.

My attempts were as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void WriteMappedHeaders()
    {

        var data = new List<Data> { 
            new Data { Name ="Ninga", Age=24 },
        };

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<HeaderConstMap>();
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DataMap>();
            csv.WriteHeader<HeaderConstMap>();
            csv.NextRecord();
            csv.WriteRecords(data);
            writer.Flush();
            var result = writer.ToString();
            var expected = new StringBuilder();
            expected.AppendLine("Header,Header");
            expected.AppendLine("FullName,Age as of now");
            expected.AppendLine("Ninja,24");
            Assert.AreEqual(expected.ToString(), result);
        }
    }


    public class HeaderConst
    {
        public string Header1 { get; set; }
        public string Header2 { get; set; }

    }

    public class HeaderConstMap : ClassMap<HeaderConst>
    {
        public HeaderConstMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Header1).Index(0).Name("Header");
            Map(m => m.Header2).Index(1).Name("Header");
        }
    }


    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }


    public class DataMap : ClassMap<Data>
    {

        public DataMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Name).Index(0).Name("FullName");
            Map(m => m.Age).Index(1).Name("Age as of now");
        }
    }
```

The exception thrown at the line where I called

```
    csv.WriteHeader<HeaderConstMap>();
```

Appreciated if anyone could give me a postive lead to fix the issue.

RSF

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
Actaully I was doing the things incorrectly.

However, just posting solutions for benefits of others.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void WriteMappedHeaders()
    {

        var data = new List<Data> { 
           new Data { Age=24, Name="Ninja"},
           new Data { Age=25, Name="Kid"}
        };

        var headers = new List<HeaderConst>();

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {

                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<HeaderConstMap>();
                csv.WriteHeader<HeaderConst>();
                csv.Configuration.UnregisterClassMap<HeaderConstMap>();
                csv.NextRecord();
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DataMap>();
                csv.WriteHeader<Data>();
                csv.NextRecord();
                csv.WriteRecords(data);
                csv.Configuration.UnregisterClassMap<DataMap>();
            }
            writer.Flush();
            var result = writer.ToString();
            var expected = new StringBuilder();
            expected.AppendLine("Header,Header");
            expected.AppendLine("FullName,Age as of now");
            expected.AppendLine("Ninja,24");
            expected.AppendLine("Kid,25");
            Assert.AreEqual(expected.ToString(), result);
        }

    }

    public class HeaderConst
    {
        public string Header1 { get; set; }
        public string Header2 { get; set; }

    }

    public class HeaderConstMap : ClassMap<HeaderConst>
    {
        public HeaderConstMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Header1).Index(0).Name("Header");
            Map(m => m.Header2).Index(1).Name("Header");
        }
    }


    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }


    public class DataMap : ClassMap<Data>
    {

        public DataMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Name).Index(0).Name("FullName");
            Map(m => m.Age).Index(1).Name("Age as of now");
        }
    }
```